# Give response to the client without depending on processing -Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-listeners

I am sending a request to the Servlet(which is hosted on Tomcat).

What that Servlet do:

Query the database and get file names and delete those files which are located in folders.

What I need?

This kind of operation taking much time because there is a case where I have to delete some 200-300 files. So I need to call a task which works in background and response of the servlet should not wait for the task completion.

Finally:

Servlet should be able to start a task with a request and he have to get response immediately(without depending on task processing).

I am not talking about AJAX.

Comment: Deleting 20-100 files should be quite fast, but anyway, look at the Executors class. Create an Executor service when the app starts, and submit tasks to the executor to run them in the background.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to process your task in asynchronous way. You should consider one of well known implementations in Spring @[Async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) or EJB @[Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).